# How to make containing function to Stop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to programming.

I don't why the function is repeating twice.

I assume this is happening because return statement is still making `for (let post of posts)` start again/ run again. I want the containing function to stop as soon as
return is present inside child function.

Can someone help me understand why it is happening and how can I stop this looping.

```
 const getPosts = () => {
        console.log('current location', window.location.href);

for (let post of posts) {
            console.log('.....for loop starts here');

          switch (post.matchType) {
                case 'contains':
                    console.log('contains');
                    if (
                        currentUrl
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .includes(post.url.toLowerCase())
                    ) {
                        for (let item of workingArray)
                            if (item === post._id) {
                            
                                console.log(
                                    '.....................oops item already seen'
                                );
                                setVisibility(false);
                                return;
                            }

                        setVisibility(true);
                        setActivePosts(post);
                        return post;
                    }

                    break;

                case 'equals':
                    console.log('equals');

                    if (currentUrl.toLowerCase() === post.url.toLowerCase()) {
                        for (let item of workingArray)
                            if (item === post._id) {
                         
                                console.log(
                                    '.....................oops item already seen'
                                );
                                setVisibility(false);
                                return;
                            }
                        setVisibility(true);
                        setActivePosts(post);
                        return post;
                    }
                    break;
}
```

```
current location http://localhost:8080/
.....for loop starts here 
equals
current location http://localhost:8080/
 .....for loop starts here
equals
```

I'm calling getPosts() in the render like this ...

```
return (
     
                    <Simplecomponent
                      posts={getPosts()}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `getPosts ` function in your component?

Comment: Thansk for the heads up. I have edited the question.

Comment: Use brackets around your `for` loops' content. Also, what do you think `return` does inside a `for` loop?

Comment: @HereticMonkey for loop is  inside `getPosts` function so we can still use `return`

Comment: @Abhishek The question was not directed to you. I asked to gauge the OP's understanding of how that `return` affects the function, since there are several places where `return` is used without a return value.

Comment: @HereticMonkey 

In some cases, I have tried to return with a value and in other cases...just to get out of that loop. What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: @Abhishek I want to the switch case statement to be executed only when currentURL ====post.url.... In all other cases, i want to break out of that switch case.

Comment: @Tomaz_ so you need to execute switch if only the currentUrl === post.url?

Comment: `return` does not exit the loop; it exits the function. To exit a `for` loop, one uses `break`. To exit an iteration and move to the next value in the loop, use `continue`.

Comment: @Abhishek So if it goes to "equal case" then execute things only if currentUrl === post.url.

Else go to next item in for loop and start matching cases again.

Comment: I would expect a function named `getPosts()` to return an array of post objects, not set visibility and stuff like that. You might want to look into the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

Comment: @Abhishek It changes.

Comment: @Tomaz_ So the for loop is running twice? right then check the place where the `getPost()` is called.

Comment: @Abhishek ....it's called inside the react render method